# Prevent XCode 4 from enabling assistent doing debug?

Tags: xcode4

Every time I debug my code in XCode 4 and I have several breakpoints, XCode 4 eventually will turn on the assistant and start displaying the breakpoints in the second split panel.

I find it pretty annoying and would really like to disable it. Is is possible? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems like the issue is gone in the latest build in XCode 4.4.1